# Legal JSON giving error in IE: Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, mootools

I have a strange IE error, and all i can find on google is that the error should come when you have a trailing comma in a dictionary or an array. But since my JSON is perfectly leagal according to JSONLint, i am getting really frustrated.. The JSON is listed here. My question is. Did anyone experience this error where it wasn't ","-related ? Any help or guidance would be greatly apreciated..

By the way the error shows up in any JSON decoder i have tried, but the one i want to use is mootools JSON.decode

```
{
    "spine": [
        "title.xml",
        "about.xml",
        "main0.xml",
        "main1.xml",
        "main2.xml",
        "main3.xml",
        "main4.xml",
        "main5.xml",
        "main6.xml",
        "main7.xml",
        "main8.xml",
        "main9.xml",
        "main10.xml",
        "main11.xml",
        "similar.xml",
        "feedbooks.xml"
    ],
    "chapters": {
        "main9.xml": "TEST",
        "similar.xml": "TEST",
        "title.xml": "TEST",
        "main10.xml": "TEST",
        "feedbooks.xml": "TEST",
        "about.xml": "TEST",
        "main0.xml": "TEST",
        "main5.xml": "TEST",
        "main4.xml": "TEST",
        "main8.xml": "TEST",
        "main6.xml": "TEST",
        "main11.xml": "TEST",
        "main3.xml": "TEST",
        "main1.xml": "TEST",
        "main7.xml": "TEST",
        "main2.xml": "TEST"
    },
    "manifest": {
        "ncx": {
            "href": "fb.ncx",
            "media-type": "application/x-dtbncx+xml"
        },
        "titlepage": {
            "href": "title.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "logo-feedbooks": {
            "href": "images/logo-feedbooks.png",
            "media-type": "image/png"
        },
        "logo-feedbooks-tiny": {
            "href": "images/logo-feedbooks-tiny.png",
            "media-type": "image/png"
        },
        "about-css": {
            "href": "css/about.css",
            "media-type": "text/css"
        },
        "feedbooks": {
            "href": "feedbooks.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main8": {
            "href": "main8.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main9": {
            "href": "main9.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main0": {
            "href": "main0.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main1": {
            "href": "main1.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main2": {
            "href": "main2.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main3": {
            "href": "main3.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main4": {
            "href": "main4.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main5": {
            "href": "main5.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main6": {
            "href": "main6.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main7": {
            "href": "main7.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main10": {
            "href": "main10.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main11": {
            "href": "main11.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "newspaper-css": {
            "href": "css/newspaper.css",
            "media-type": "text/css"
        },
        "page-css": {
            "href": "css/page.css",
            "media-type": "text/css"
        },
        "about": {
            "href": "about.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        },
        "main-css": {
            "href": "css/main.css",
            "media-type": "text/css"
        },
        "titlepage-css": {
            "href": "css/title.css",
            "media-type": "text/css"
        },
        "feedbooks-css": {
            "href": "css/feedbooks.css",
            "media-type": "text/css"
        },
        "similar": {
            "href": "similar.xml",
            "media-type": "application/xhtml+xml"
        }
    },
    "spinereal": [
        "title.xml",
        "about.xml",
        "main0.xml",
        "main1.xml",
        "main2.xml",
        "main3.xml",
        "main4.xml",
        "main5.xml",
        "main6.xml",
        "main7.xml",
        "main8.xml",
        "main9.xml",
        "main10.xml",
        "main11.xml",
        "similar.xml",
        "feedbooks.xml"
    ],
    "contents": [
        {
            "src": "title.xml",
            "id": "level1-titlepage",
            "title": "Title"
        },
        {
            "src": "about.xml",
            "id": "level1-about",
            "title": "About"
        },
        {
            "src": "main0.xml",
            "id": "chap578",
            "title": "Chapter 1"
        },
        {
            "src": "main1.xml",
            "id": "chap580",
            "title": "Chapter 2"
        },
        {
            "src": "main2.xml",
            "id": "chap582",
            "title": "Chapter 3"
        },
        {
            "src": "main3.xml",
            "id": "chap584",
            "title": "Chapter 4"
        },
        {
            "src": "main4.xml",
            "id": "chap586",
            "title": "Chapter 5"
        },
        {
            "src": "main5.xml",
            "id": "chap588",
            "title": "Chapter 6"
        },
        {
            "src": "main6.xml",
            "id": "chap590",
            "title": "Chapter 7"
        },
        {
            "src": "main7.xml",
            "id": "chap592",
            "title": "Chapter 8"
        },
        {
            "src": "main8.xml",
            "id": "chap594",
            "title": "Chapter 9"
        },
        {
            "src": "main9.xml",
            "id": "chap596",
            "title": "Chapter 10"
        },
        {
            "src": "main10.xml",
            "id": "chap598",
            "title": "Chapter 11"
        },
        {
            "src": "main11.xml",
            "id": "chap600",
            "title": "Chapter 12"
        },
        {
            "src": "similar.xml",
            "id": "level1-similar",
            "title": "Recommendations"
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "publisher": "TEST",
        "rights": "TEST",
        "description": "TEST",
        "language": "TEST",
        "creator": "TEST",
        "title": "TEST",
        "source": "TEST",
        "coverage": "",
        "date": "TEST",
        "identifier": "TEST",
        "subject": "TEST"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok guys.. i've kind of solved my problem.. The way i was getting the json was from Django, i assumed i could simple take the simplejson.dump of my dictionary and then use it in a template like this:

```
var opf = {{ var }}
```

This worked perfectly fine in webkit and mozilla browsers, however IE choked on it with the mysterious error on that exact line. So.. What i tried was

```
var opf = JSON.decode({{var}});
```

and

```
var opf = JSON.decode("{{var}}");
```

which generated the exact same error but now the error happened somewhere in mootools. I tried everything.. :/ so what i ended up doing, was to make a Request.JSON instead so that i dont pass the variable to the template. Now IE suddently play nicely :/ i feel it is a bit of a hack, but what the heck. Thanks for the quick replies guys..

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON? One of the libraries from http://json.org? `eval`?

Comment: please show us the involved javascript

Comment: Tried it with IE8 and just eval() and no problem

Comment: Answering my own question (possibly incorrectly), Dimitar Christoff points out in a comment on my answer below that as the post is tagged `mootools`, the OP is probably using MooTools' own `JSON.decode`. But we'll have to wait for Jakob to say one way or the other.

Comment: Re your update: If you quote what actually goes to the browser when you do `var opf = JSON.decode({{var}});`, we can probably help you de-hack it. My guess is you need to pre-process what Django is giving you to make sure any quotes and other special characters are escaped (and then put the whole thing in quotes). But that's a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer**:

I think it must be an error *elsewhere* on the page. Dimitar pointed out below that you tagged your question `mootools` and so are probably using `JSON.decode`, but that works fine:

```
var obj, json;
json = '...your JSON...';
obj = JSON.decode(json);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ofere4/4)

**Alternately**: If what you've quoted appears *literally* in your JavaScript code (not enclosed in a string, not being loaded from the server via XHR or something), then what you've quoted is a JavaScript object literal, not JSON, and you don't parse it at all. Simplified example:

JavaScript object literal:

```
var obj = {
    foo: "bar"
};
```

Quotes around the property names are optional in an object literal (not so in JSON, where they're required), so this is fine too:

```
var obj = {
    "foo": "bar"
};
```

JSON:

```
var json = '{' +
           '   "foo": "bar"' +
           '}';
var obj = JSON.decode(json);
```

---

**Original answer**: *(having missed the `mootools` tag)*

It works fine with json2.js, even back on IE6:

```
var obj, json;
json = '...your JSON...';
obj = JSON.parse(json); // where `json` is a string containing your JSON
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ofere4)

Sounds like a problem with how it's being parsed, or perhaps a problem *elsewhere* in the code.

If you're using raw `eval`, be sure you wrap the JSON in parentheses:

```
var obj, json;
json = '...your JSON...';
obj = eval('(' + json + ')');
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ofere4/2)

...but I wouldn't recommend using `eval` to parse JSON (not even json2, which uses `eval` under the covers) unless you're sure of the source (e.g., your own server). I'd probably use one of the non-`eval` parsers from [Crockford's github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/).

Comment: he probably uses mootools' JSON.decode / encode methods - which is also fine in ie8 - http://jsfiddle.net/EBqte/1/